# Convert variable to multiple columns with Pandas

Tags: pandas, variables, pivot

I have a legacy datafile that contains data in the following format:

```
SURVEY  NUM TEMPORAL
WHS 1   Byz
WHS 1   Byz_Um
WHS 1   IAII
WHS 1   L_Isl
WHS 1   L_Rom
WHS 1   Mod
WHS 1   Nab
WHS 2   Byz
WHS 2   Mod
WHS 2   Unk
WHS 2   MP
WHS 3   Byz
WHS 3   Nab
WHS 3   LMP
WHS 3   UP
WHS 4   LMP
WHS 4   MP
WHS 4   UP
WHS 5   Byz
WHS 5   Unk
WHS 5   LMP
```

etc..

Essentially, the column "NUM" is a unique identifier that relates to a specific site, and the column "TEMPORAL" is a value associated with that site. For whatever reason, the original file repeates this over several lines for sites with mutltiple temporal occupations (this archaeological data). I would like to use Pandas to conver this to something like so:

```
SURVEY NUM  Byz Byz_Um IAII L_Isl LMP L_Rom Nab MP Mod Unk UP
WHS 1   1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
WHS 2   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1
WHS 3   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0
WHS 4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1
WHS 5   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

Where a 1 is placed into a new column if that TEMPORAL period exists. I tried using `df.pivot` with "NUM" as the index and "TEMPORAL" as the columns, but that did not work. There are several thousand sites in this database, so doing it manually is not a possibility. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`np.bincount` and `pd.factorize`**

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df['SURVEY'])
j, c = pd.factorize(df['NUM TEMPORAL'])
n, m = len(r), len(c)

b = np.bincount(i * m + j, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m)

pd.DataFrame(b, r, c)

       Byz  Byz_Um  IAII  L_Isl  L_Rom  Mod  Nab  Unk  MP  LMP  UP
WHS 1    1       1     1      1      1    1    1    0   0    0   0
WHS 2    1       0     0      0      0    1    0    1   1    0   0
WHS 3    1       0     0      0      0    0    1    0   0    1   1
WHS 4    0       0     0      0      0    0    0    0   1    1   1
WHS 5    1       0     0      0      0    0    0    1   0    1   0
```

---

**`pd.get_dummies` and `pd.DataFrame.dot`**

```
pd.get_dummies(df['SURVEY']).T.dot(pd.get_dummies(df['NUM TEMPORAL']))

       Byz  Byz_Um  IAII  LMP  L_Isl  L_Rom  MP  Mod  Nab  UP  Unk
WHS 1    1       1     1    0      1      1   0    1    1   0    0
WHS 2    1       0     0    0      0      0   1    1    0   0    1
WHS 3    1       0     0    1      0      0   0    0    1   1    0
WHS 4    0       0     0    1      0      0   1    0    0   1    0
WHS 5    1       0     0    1      0      0   0    0    0   0    1
```

---

**`pd.crosstab`**

```
pd.crosstab(*df.values.T)

col_0  Byz  Byz_Um  IAII  LMP  L_Isl  L_Rom  MP  Mod  Nab  UP  Unk
row_0                                                             
WHS 1    1       1     1    0      1      1   0    1    1   0    0
WHS 2    1       0     0    0      0      0   1    1    0   0    1
WHS 3    1       0     0    1      0      0   0    0    1   1    0
WHS 4    0       0     0    1      0      0   1    0    0   1    0
WHS 5    1       0     0    1      0      0   0    0    0   0    1
```

Or

```
pd.crosstab(df['SURVEY'], df['NUM TEMPORAL'])

NUM TEMPORAL  Byz  Byz_Um  IAII  LMP  L_Isl  L_Rom  MP  Mod  Nab  UP  Unk
SURVEY                                                                   
WHS 1           1       1     1    0      1      1   0    1    1   0    0
WHS 2           1       0     0    0      0      0   1    1    0   0    1
WHS 3           1       0     0    1      0      0   0    0    1   1    0
WHS 4           0       0     0    1      0      0   1    0    0   1    0
WHS 5           1       0     0    1      0      0   0    0    0   0    1
```

---

**`reconstruction`**

```
pd.Series(1, df.values.T.tolist()).unstack(fill_value=0)

       Byz  Byz_Um  IAII  LMP  L_Isl  L_Rom  MP  Mod  Nab  UP  Unk
WHS 1    1       1     1    0      1      1   0    1    1   0    0
WHS 2    1       0     0    0      0      0   1    1    0   0    1
WHS 3    1       0     0    1      0      0   0    0    1   1    0
WHS 4    0       0     0    1      0      0   1    0    0   1    0
WHS 5    1       0     0    1      0      0   0    0    0   0    1
```

**Explanation**

- `df.values.T.tolist()` passes a list of length 2, consisting of two levels.  Those levels get interpreted as a MultiIndex.
- `1` becomes the default value.
- `unstack` with `fill_value=0` reshapes accordingly

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful and complete answer. I researched each suggestion, and the ones that make the most sense to me are `pd.get_dummies` and `pd.crosstab`. In this particular case, I was able to get `pd.crosstab` to do exactly what I want with the following line: ` df2 = pandas.crosstab(df['NUM'], [df['SURVEY'], df['TEMPORAL']])`. I forgot to mention that there were two surveys, so this way works very well. I apparently don't have enough reputation points to mark your answer as the best one, so hopefully others will upvote.

Answer (score 2):

By using `get_dummies`

```
df.set_index(['SURVEY','NUM']).TEMPORAL.str.get_dummies().sum(level=1)
Out[127]: 
     Byz  Byz_Um  IAII  LMP  L_Isl  L_Rom  MP  Mod  Nab  UP  Unk
NUM                                                             
1      1       1     1    0      1      1   0    1    1   0    0
2      1       0     0    0      0      0   1    1    0   0    1
3      1       0     0    1      0      0   0    0    1   1    0
4      0       0     0    1      0      0   1    0    0   1    0
5      1       0     0    1      0      0   0    0    0   0    1
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I was not aware of `pd.get_dummies`, and it definitely seems like a tool that is applicable to a situation such as this. However, I was able to get what I wanted with `pd.crosstab` as suggested in the other answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to piRSquared for leading me to the correct answer. The following code did exactly what I wanted:

```
df2 = pandas.crosstab(df['NUM'], [df['SURVEY'], df['TEMPORAL']])
```